# as mine - as I (am). semantics

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, american-english, british-english, semantics

I've asked a similar question before, but my thread is closed. As I've learned from previous thread, both these sentences are grammatical. My question is: what is the meaning difference between these two?

You're in the same situation as mine.

You're in the same situation as I (am).

[As mine vs. As I am - academical](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/574419/as-mine-vs-as-i-am-academical)

Comment: I edited my question accordingly.

Comment: People would usually say "as me" although it is not strictly grammatical. The first is correct, but not idiomatic.

Comment: _As me_ is fully grammatical. Strictly. Really. Honestly. There are dozens of ways to say just about anything in English. And "what people would usually say" is, by definition, "strictly grammatical"; that's what _strictly grammatical_ **means**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference is the pair of things being compared. There should be a parallel between the two.

With “as mine”, the things compared are ‘your situation’ and ‘my situation’.

With “as I”, “as I am” and “as me”, the comparison is between ‘you’ and ‘me’.

Comment: Thank you. So, I shall assume second as the extent of the situation the persons in.

Comment: @kursat42 You’re welcome. Yes, the first example says their situations have something in common whereas the second says the _people_ have something in common (the thing being the “situation”).